# When i click on my button my app crashes

Tags: java, android, xml, eclipse

i'm fairly new to coding but decided i would take the huge plunge into the ocean without knowing how to swim, anyway my button keeps failling to open my new activity when i click on it, instead it just crashes. when I run it on my emulator i get a message saying that it has stopped. I'm using a genymotion emulator and the darcula android studio version.

**My main activity.xml:**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:background="@drawable/background_black">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/unpressed_button"
        android:background="@drawable/unpressed"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**My second Activity.xml:**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:background="@drawable/background_black"
    tools:context="quirkykoders.flash_flash.Pressed_Button">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/pressed_button"
        android:background="@drawable/pressed"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

**My Manifest**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="quirkykoders.flash_flash" >

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".Pressed_Button"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_pressed__button" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.PRESSED" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

**My java**

```
package quirkykoders.flash_flash;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
   private static Button button_sbm;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        OnClickButtonListener();
    }

   public void OnClickButtonListener() {
   button_sbm = (Button)findViewById(R.id.unpressed_button);
   button_sbm.setOnClickListener(
           new View.OnClickListener() {
               @Override
               public void onClick(View v) {
                   Intent intent = new Intent ("quirkykoders.flash_flash.Pressed_Button");
                   startActivity(intent);
               }
           }
   );

   }
}
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated

Comment: are you receiving an error in android studio? If so, post it please

Comment: I think problem is in Intent, why are using this intent? is it for opening secondActivity?

Comment: See this link: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#Intent(java.lang.String)

You are passing the name of activity as action. You must use different constructor: new Intent(MainActivity.this, Pressed_Button.class);

Comment: This is a lot of code to review.

Answer (score 1):

When you want to create A new Activity you have to send two parameters in the intent object First is currentActivity name and the second is CallingActivity name

```
    Intent intent=new Intent(MainActivity.this,Pressed_Button.class);
    startActivity(intent);
```